# How to skip test if before failed?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I use protractor + jasmine. I have a test as below:

```
describe('Suite', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        // do precondition
    });

    it('Test', function() {
        // do test
    });
});
```

If my precondition was failed my test will execute. But I would like to skip test in this case. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using `pending()` if your condition is met?

Link in Jasmine: https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.0/global.html#pending

Comment: It seems it works. Thank you)